How to return data in SOAP from Promise
I created a SOAP server in Node.js
const soap = require('soap');
const http = require('http');
const XMLWriter = require('xml-writer');

const service = {
   ImpDispatcherService: {
      ImpDispatcher: {
         performTest: function (args) {
            const xw = new XMLWriter(true);
            xw.startDocument();
            xw.startElement('result');
            queryDatabase(args.parameter1, xw).then(success => {
               console.log(success);
               xw.endDocument();
               console.log(xw.toString()); // -> prints the full XML-File
            });             
            return { testResult: xw.toString() };
         }
      }
   }
};

var server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
   response.end('404: Not Found: ' + request.url);
});

// Create the SOAP server
const xml = require('fs').readFileSync(`${__dirname}/ImpDispatcherService.wsdl`, 'utf8');
var server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
   response.end('404: Not Found: ' + request.url);
});

server.listen(8000, 'localhost');
soap.listen(server, '/imp', service, xml, () => {
   logger.info('Server initialized');
});

async function queryDatabase(pars) {
   const oracledb = require('oracledb');
   const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(db);
   const result = await connection.execute(`BEGIN :ret := getResult(${pars}); END;`, {ret: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR } });
   let row;
   while (row = await result.outBinds.ret.getRow()) {
      xw.writeElement('tag', row.blabla);
   }

   return true;
}

When I make a SOAP request from client, then it returns only empty <result/> element but not the elements I added inside queryDatabase().

performTest: function (args) {
  queryDatabase(args.parameter1).then(result => {
    return result;
  });
}

You don't have a return statement in performTest, so it's implicitly returning undefined, instead of a promise. Also, .then(result => result) has no effect. The promise created by queryDatabase will already resolve to result.
Try this instead:
performTest: function (args) {
  return queryDatabase(args.parameter1)
}


Thanks for reply. Looks like I simplified my code too much. Please have a look at updated question.

I found a solution:
const service = {
   ImpDispatcherService: {
      ImpDispatcher: {
         performTest: queryDatabase
      }
   }
}

async function queryDatabase(args) {
   const xw = new XMLWriter(true);
   xw.startDocument();
   xw.startElement('result');
   await queryDatabase(args.parameter1, xw);
   xw.endDocument();
   
   return { testResult: xw.toString() };
}

However, I did not manage it to define the function inside the service object. But this is mainly cosmetic.
